# Firebase - Firestore - create a function to verify if a user exists in Auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to verify if a user exists in the Authentication list of users in firebase. I know I can use:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
```

I am building a react native app, so I can't install firebase-admin since it would require I ship credentials in the app, which is too dangerous, since someone can do reverse engineering and find them.

I have found I can write functions, so I have created a separate project to create and deploy functions, this will work as a backend.

Now I want to create a function there that uses firebase-admin and to be able to use the 2 methods listed above.

I found I can create:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

and call it like:

```
var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({text: messageText}).then(function(result) {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
});
```

Not sure if using https.onCall is the best for this case or is there a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the documentation indicates - accessible [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) - and the fact that the `https.onCall()` uses a safe method to be called (HTTPS) **I believe that this is the best option for your case, since installing firebase-admin doesn't fit your case.**

The official documentation [Protocol specification for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) also says:

> If you are able to use the Android, iOS, or web SDKs, you're recommended to do that instead of directly implementing this protocol. The SDKs provide features to save coding time and effort, as detailed in [Call Functions from Your App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

So, this is indicated, in case you don't want/can use the [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk), which I believe it's what you are saying. Considering that, I believe that the `https.onCall()` it's the option for your situation.

Let me know if the information helped you!